# onCreateview of fragment set value to Global variable return null value?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

i am stuck within a fragment.below is my fragment code

```
public class Tab1 extends Fragment {
    EditText address,contactNumber,dob;
    String adds;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_1,container,false);

        contactNumber= (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editTextcontact);
        address= (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        dob= (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editText3);

        contactNumber.setHint("Your ContactNo Plz");
        address.setHint("Your address Plz");
        dob.setHint("Your Data Of Birth");
//receive data from main activity
        TabedActivity activity = (TabedActivity) getActivity();
        String myDataFromActivity = activity.getMyData();
//
       adds=address.getText().toString();

        return v;
    }

    public String getData(){
      return adds;
    }
}
```

what i want is when this fragment is called from the main activity the text in the edittext should pass to the adds variable.i check it like above but it show me a null value.how could i set this value.?please help

Comment: Where/when in your Activity do you call getData()?

Comment: @UdiIdan in my main activity onOptionItemSelected i call this function will it be right or not?                                                                                            public void ShoValue(){

Tab1 tab=new Tab1();
addre=tab.getData().toString();

    Toast.makeText(this, "you select done "+addre, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

Comment: The user suppose to enter the text, right? so how would it be available when you do Tab1 tab=new Tab1(); addre=tab.getData().toString();? also, you have a problem in your onCreateVieew method which I wrote in my answer

Comment: what is the problem and where is your answer ?

Comment: You have several problems:
1. You instantiate a Fragment and in the next line you're trying to get a value from it.
2. You refernce an EditText in onCreateView, and then in the same method try to get a value, even though the user didn't have the chance to enter it yet.

Answer (score 0):

You need return address.getText().toString() and check for null;

Sample:

```
public String getData(){
      if(address != null && address.getText() != null) 
      return address.getText().toString(); 
      return null; // block NPE
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In onCreateView you do:

```
address= (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);
```

and in the same event you then do:

```
adds=address.getText().toString();
```

but offcourse the user at this point didn't set its value yet.

That said, it's  also important to check when in your activity are you trying to get this value.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass your desired data to fragment from your parent activity while creating fragment. Sample code can be like below

```
 Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("address", address);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
```

Now in your fragment get the value back like

```
getArguments().getString("address");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: #Amit Kumar please have a look on my[ this question] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33459676/on-option-item-selected-want-to-execute-the-fragment-method)